# Probability Question - Conditional Probability Staff

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

80% of the company staff is male.
20% of the company staff is female.

57% of the staff's highest qualification is Ordinary Level.
32% of the staff's highest qualification is Advanced Level.
Other's are graduates.

40% of the female staff's highest qualification is Ordinary Level.
45% of the female staff's highest qualification is Advanced Level.
Other females are Graduates.

Now we choose a random person from the staff.

**What I did**

$80$ males + $20$ females

$40$ percent of $20$ females is $8$ OL females
$45$ percent of $20$ females is $9$ AL females
$15$ percent of $20$ females is $3$ Graduate females

Then $57-8$ = $49$ are up to OL males
And $32-9$=$23$ are up to AL males.
So $11-3$=$8$ are up to Graduate males.

1. What is the probability of choosing a female whose highest qualification is Ordinary Level?

$$\frac{20}{100} \times \frac{40}{100} = \frac{8}{100}$$

2. What is the probability of choosing a male whose highest qualification is Ordinary Level?

$$ \frac{49}{100}$$

3. What is the probability of choosing a graduate, given that it is a male?

$$ \frac{8}{80}$$

4)What is the probability of choosing a female, given that it is a non-graduate staff member?

$$ \frac{\frac{17}{100}}{\frac{89}{100}}=\frac{17}{89}$$

Am I doing something wrong?

My book answers are not the same except for first question.

Comment: This all seems reasonable.  What answers did the book give?  Are you certain they are different values and not merely just written differently but same value?

Comment: Are Graduates higher than Ordinary Level?

Comment: @RobertShore yes